# Merging 2 SQLite database files without windows server

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 android SQLite database files which I want to combine into a single one. Are there any easy available tools for this ?

Comment: By what logic do you want to merge the two databases? SQLite has no server anyway, so "without Windows server" makes very little sense. My suggestion is to export the two databases to text files, then to merge the text files and lastly to import the merged text file into the new merged database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SQLite Studio (You need to export the data from the both the databases and import the data to a newly created database.) 
https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download

Comment: I've been searching for days for such software! You are a true life saver <3

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)